# How can I add a new database entry upon user registration with Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm starting to learn Django and have a class called `Customer` in my models.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True)
    cart = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order)

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
```

I'm importing `django.contrib.auth` to register users to the database, but I would like to also initialize a `Customer` object upon registration.

I first attempted to override the `save()` method from the `UserCreationForm` and `initialize` a `Customer` object there:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        customer = Customer(user)
        customer.save()
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

But it did not seem to create a `Customer` object.

Alternatively, is it better to extend the `User` class to have the `Customer` class fields? I initially thought I should keep authentication separate, which is why I created the `Customer` class.

Comment: Please include the `Customer` model in your question. You would need to create it with the required data with something like `Customer.objects.create(user=user)`

Comment: @markwalker_ Thanks! I just added the Customer model. I tried to add that line that you wrote, but it didn't seem to work :(

Comment: You'll need to debug it then (your updated question doesn't pass the user instance as a kwarg which is different to my suggestion), and perhaps read the docs, because that's a valid way to create your `Customer` object assuming that your `UserCreationForm` creates a `User` instance; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 1):

Might be better if you created a signal instead!

```py
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from path.to.models import Customer

@receiver(signals.post_save, sender = User)
def create_customer(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        c = Customer(...) #create your customer object
        c.save()
```

and in apps.py, import signals to run it.